# Remove Node from xml by attribute

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have this example xml:

```
<Forms>
<Form Desc="sasld" DocType="1">
    <topmostSubform ind="0">
        <HouseNo ind="0">413</HouseNo>
        <ZipCode ind="0">82051</ZipCode>
        <PostOfficeBox ind="0">0</PostOfficeBox>
    </topmostSubform>
</Form>
<Form Desc="abcd" DocType="1">
    <topmostSubform ind="0">
        <TextField1 ind="24" />
        <TextField1 ind="25" />
        <TextField1 ind="26" />
        <DisContActivity-5-0 ind="0" />
        <DisWithFranActivity-5-0 ind="0" />
    </topmostSubform>
</Form>
<Form Desc="abcd" DocType="5">
    <topmostSubform ind="0">
        <TextField1 ind="24" />
        <TextField1 ind="25" />
    </topmostSubform>
</Form>
```

I want to remove all nodes which are of type Form and its DocType attribute value is 1.

I hold this xml in a Document object.

i tried:

```
String xpath_string = "//Form[@DocType ='1']";
        XPathExpression xPathExpr = XPATH.compile(xpath_string);
        Object result_obj = xPathExpr.evaluate(document,XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result_obj;
        System.out.println(nodes.getLength());
        for(int i=1;i<nodes.getLength();i++)
            document.removeChild(nodes.item(i));
```

But it gives "NOT_FOUND_ERR".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.removeChild(nodes.item(i));
```

attempts to remove a child node from the document node. But the node you're trying to remove isn't a child of the document node, it's a child of the `Forms` element. Try this instead:

```
nodes.item(i).getParentNode().removeChild(nodes.item(i);
```

Your `for` loop also needs to start from 0, not 1, as DOM node list indexes are 0-based.